# custom date picker popup excel 2010

Tags: excel, datepicker, vba

i found this amazing date picker form a team of people made available for custom use in excel version that do not support calendar control.
I added this to another WB of mine so that every time a user clicks a column that requires a date, the datepicker userform would appear and then enter the selected date in the cell.

Now I am trying to utilize this with a userform I created. I added a text box that auto populates today's date when the userform opens, but I want to somehow get the datepickerform to pop up on click of the date text box. I added `private sub textbox_change() datepickerform.show` but am receiving a **run-time error 91** "object variable or With block variable not set".

The debugger brings me to this part of the DatePickerForm code with the first line highlighted.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

If IsDate(Target.Value) Then
    Calendar1.Value = Target.Value
End If

Call MoveToTarget

End Sub
```

Is this flagging because my text box is not in a date format?
I can share the full code on request, it's just that it's **alot** and I didn't want to add to my already lengthy post.

here is the code for the datepickerform:

```
Option Explicit


Private WithEvents Calendar1 As cCalendar

Public Target As Range

Private Sub Calendar1_Click()
    Call CloseDatePicker(True)
End Sub

Private Sub Calendar1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyEscape Then
        Call CloseDatePicker(False)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    If Calendar1 Is Nothing Then
        Set Calendar1 = New cCalendar
        With Calendar1
            .Add_Calendar_into_Frame Me.Frame1
            .UseDefaultBackColors = False
            .DayLength = 3
            .MonthLength = mlENShort
            .Height = 120
            .Width = 180
            .GridFont.Size = 7
            .DayFont.Size = 7
            .Refresh
        End With
        Me.Height = 153 'Win7 Aero
        Me.Width = 197
    End If
End Sub



Public Sub MoveToTarget()
    Dim dLeft As Double, dTop As Double

    dLeft = Target.Left - ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Left + ActiveWindow.Left
    If dLeft > Application.Width - Me.Width Then
        dLeft = Application.Width - Me.Width
    End If
    dLeft = dLeft + Application.Left

    dTop = Target.Top - ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Top + ActiveWindow.Top
    If dTop > Application.Height - Me.Height Then
        dTop = Application.Height - Me.Height
    End If
    dTop = dTop + Application.Top

    Me.Left = IIf(dLeft > 0, dLeft, 0)
    Me.Top = IIf(dTop > 0, dTop, 0)
End Sub


Sub CloseDatePicker(Save As Boolean)
    If Save And Not Target Is Nothing And IsDate(Calendar1.Value) Then
        Target.Value = Calendar1.Value
    End If
    Set Target = Nothing

    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: The calendar date picker is it's own object and must be created within your userform. The initialization code of your userform could create that date picker object and unhide it when the date control is selected on your userform. The run-time error is complaining because you haven't created the date picker object anywhere. If you want to create the date picker object outside of your userform, then create a property of the userform to "let" the external date picker object assign to a userform variable.

Comment: After a while of playing with it, I got the custom date picker form to pop up when I select the designated text box of my main user form, however when I select a date, it doesn't change the value of the text box. I actually did away with the above userform activate completely and it will pop up and close properly, it just doesn't update the value of the text box.

Comment: Without seeing the code for the date picker, or knowing more about it, there's no way for me to tell how/what the date picker object updates, i.e. how to connect the date picker to your text box (or a worksheet cell, or anything).

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post with the date picker form code. I also figured I would share the original source for the custom date picker for anyone using a version of excel that does not support calendar control.
https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50/calendar-control-class#TOC-UPDATES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was much simpler than I thought, I think I just over think the complexity of the code often times as I'm very new to VBA and hardly know much.

I altered the close string and haven't had any issues with it yet.

```
Sub CloseDatePicker(Save As Boolean)

 myUserForm.myTextBox.Text = Calendar1.Value

    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

In the event anyone is interested in this, I think I've about got my final product. I pull my main userform up on button click and use this coding to center it in the active excel window (I use dual monitor and userforms do not appear correctly using the basic settings, they pop up on the inactive screen)

```
Sub ShowForm()

With Audit_Criteria
  .StartUpPosition = 0
  .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
  .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
  .Show
End With
End Sub
```

Then when the user selects the "date" textbox on the userform, the datepickerform will pop up, overlapping the textbox located in the top right of the userform.

```
Private Sub tbDOS_Enter()
With DatePickerForm
  .StartUpPosition = 0
  .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.01 * .Width)
  .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (1.5 * .Height)
  .Show
End With
End Sub
```

I'm not sure if there is an easier way of doing this by identifying the textbox location and offsetting the datepicker from it but it's what I arrived at and with my lack of experience, don't know of another approach.